# Why doesn't StackExchange editor support auto synced source and result?

Tags: feature-request

Editing a long post seems to be very painful. This could even prevent many - at least users who are new to the editor - not to edit anything complex anymore.

1. You need to double scroll - scroll between source and result pane, and scroll inside source pane. Why not use left-right layout?
2. Why not provide a source-result synchronization feature? Which means, whenever you click somewhere in the source or result pane, the other is auto scrolled (need left-right layout to do this) and the corresponding place is high lighted.

Comment: Who's going to pay for the development of these features?

Comment: There's actually an active project that SE is working on to revamp the whole editor. You can enable it on your [meta.se account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/current) and try it in the [sandbox question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox). They do not offer a side-by-side preview, but they offer editing of rich-text format directly. I haven't followed up on the news about it, but it's still in active development and [open-source on GitHub](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is "nobody wrote code to do that for SE".

However, if that's something you'd like or would find useful, you could use an IDE such as [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) that supports that functionality. Some online IDEs, including [stackedit.io](https://stackedit.io/app) also support that feature. You could compose your question (or answer) in one of those, and then copy-paste it into the Stack Exchange question/answer box once you're happy with it.

It's probably possible to write [a userscript](https://stackapps.com) that does that, but... using an existing tool, like one of those, isn't hard, so it's somewhat unlikely someone will write a userscript for that. Still, you could try to do that if you really wanted.